# Why does my reactive programming example only print out the observable object and not its values?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

```
public class ReactiveExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, NumberFormatException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String[] names = new String[] {"Mac", "John", "Ben"};

        Observable.from(names).subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Hello " + s + "!"));

    }

}
```

I'm running this program in IntelliJ. This is the output: `rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable@5d17d83b`. I was expecting the names from the array to be read as a stream. Admittedly an incredibly simple example, but what am I not understanding here?

My Maven build config: `exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=ReactiveExample`

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was believing my IDE too much. Simplifying the ``.toString()`` expression prints the object and hash code, but leaving it throws a redundancy warning whilst printing the correct values. So ``Observable.from(names).subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Hello " + s.toString() + "!"));``

Comment: I get Mac, John, Ben printed, if I use your code.

Comment: Your code works fine, just copy/pasted it into my IDE with the same dependency. You must have done something differently.